# django lazy fetching not working?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models news mappings,news likes and news pokes which are described below:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

from cms.models.boards import Boards
from cms.models.news import News

# WE ARE AT MODELS/NEWS MAPPINGS


class NewsMappings(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    newsId = models.ForeignKey(News, db_column='newsId', max_length=11, help_text="") 
    boardId = models.ForeignKey(Boards, db_column='boardId', max_length=11, help_text="") 
    isWallPost = models.BooleanField(db_column="isWallPost", default=False, help_text="")
    masterPostTypeId = models.IntegerField(db_column="masterPostTypeId",max_length=11,help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'news_mappings'



from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from cms.models.appUsers import Users
from cms.models.newsMappings import NewsMappings


class NewsLikes(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userId = models.ForeignKey(Users, db_column='userId', max_length=11, help_text="")
    newsId = models.ForeignKey(NewsMappings, db_column='newsMappingId', max_length=11, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'news_likes'



from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from cms.models.appUsers import Users
from cms.models.newsMappings import NewsMappings
from cms.models.masterPokes import MasterPokes


class NewsPokes(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userId = models.ForeignKey(Users, db_column='userId', max_length=11)
    newsMappingId = models.ForeignKey(NewsMappings, db_column='newsMappingId', max_length=11)
    masterPokeId = models.ForeignKey(MasterPokes, db_column='masterPokeId', max_length=11)
    otherPoke = models.CharField(db_column='otherPoke', max_length=255)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'news_pokes'
```

in my templates i am passing `NewsMapping` objects.
I am using

```
newsMapping = NewsMappings.objects.all()
```

and passing newsMapping in contex as datalist.And Applying forloop on templated as `{% for item in datalist%}`

`{{item.newslikes_set.all.count}}` it gives me count related to newslikes but when i apply same to `{{item.newspokes_set.all.count}}` its not working.It always give 0.

Comment: do you have any pokes in database?

Comment: yes i do have pokes in database